# Variable behavior in VBA. Same variable holding dual values. How?

Tags: vba, variables, for-loop, scope

I was working on some legacy code and came across something which is quite new and amusing to me.

The VBA proc has a variable declared and assigned. The same variable is used for as iteration variable in the `For` loop.  The loop works fine and produces correct result.Soemhow the variable retains both values at same time, a.) Value assigned by code , b.) Value assigned in the `For` loop What I am trying to understand is how? Is it one of the less known /hidden features of `VBA` or I am just overthinking and missing a very basic concept?
Please see the sample code and comments.

```
Sub test()

    Dim lTest       As Long

    '/ Assignment here.
    lTest = 10

    '/ How this loop runs. When I assign lTest=0 in the `For` loop then
    '/ shouldn't the loop exit at lTest -1 ? If I don't assign any value to lTest, then
    '/ the loop behaves as expected and exits without any iteration.
    For lTest = 0 To lTest - 1
        Debug.Print lTest
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Use a different named iterator variable than the assigned one in loop commands.

Comment: @Parfait , good one :) . I know this is not the best practice. And your suggestion is. I asked this question just to figure out if its a glitch or there's a logical explanation behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable isn't holding 2 values at once.

Once the loop is entered, the end condition is set.

So, when you enter the loop, `lTest` is equal to 10, meaning the loop will continue until `lTest` is equal to 9.  THEN, `lTest` is set to 0 to start the loop.

It is easier to see this using 2 variables.

```
Sub test()

Dim testVar As Integer
Dim loopCounter As Integer

testVar = 10
loopCounter = 0

For loopCounter = 0 To testVar - 1

testVar = 2 'or whatever you want
Debug.Print loopCounter
Debug.Print testVar

Next loopCounter

End Sub
```

This will go until loopCounter is 9.  testVar can be set to whatever you want, but once the loop is entered, the loop will go until testVar is equal to the ending loop parameter.

Another thing causing you confusion is that you think that when you do not set `lTest` equal to anything, that it is initially being set to 0 to begin the loop.  What is actually happening is that lTest is set to 0 because it has not been given a value.  0 is the default value for a Long, so the first time you enter the loop, the end value is set to -1 because lTest is defaulted to 0, not because you start the loop with 0.  To see this, start the loop with -3 instead of 0 and it will run until the end value of -1

Comment: thanks. turns out I didn't know much about for loop. :)

Answer (score 2):

Two things happen in the `For` statement.  The exit condition is set (lTest = 9) and the counter variable is assigned an initial value (lTest = 0).  This is functionally equivalent to this:

```
lTest = 0
Do
    Debug.Print lTest
Loop While lTest < 10
```

The loop exit condition is only evaluated once regardless of the variable used, and is only set the first time the loop is entered.  This code demonstrates:

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim test As Long, jumped As Boolean

    test = 10
    For test = 0 To test
InLoop:
        Debug.Print test
        If test = 5 And Not jumped Then GoSub OutSideLoop
    Next

    Exit Sub

OutSideLoop:
    test = 0
    jumped = True
    GoTo InLoop
End Sub
```